# Calculating the entropy of a 32mb file in Perl - What is the quickest method?

Tags: perl, math, entropy

I have a 32,678kb encrypted bin file which I need the entropy of. I am using Perl as its part of a larger project.

I have so far used the following 'technique':

```
use Shannon::Entropy qw/entropy/;
my $file = "test.bin";
open(my $bin, "<", $file) or die $!; binmode $bin;
seek($bin, 0x000000, 0); 
read($bin, my $entropy, 0x01FFFFF0);
print entropy($entropy);
```

This yields an almost infinite wait time, to the point where I give up after 30+ minutes.

I cannot deviate from testing the entire file's entropy.

Is there any quicker way? Would splitting it, entropy-ing it and using some weird math to combine again result in the same entropy as if it were one file?

Comment: Try using `read_binary()` from [File::Slurper](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Slurper) to read the file.

Comment: Failing that, it's possible this entropy function is just really slow.

Comment: Looking at the [source](https://metacpan.org/source/LNATION/Shannon-Entropy-1.000000/lib/Shannon/Entropy.pm), yup, it's going to be really slow as it splits its argument into a list of characters - so 32678 elements, which it then maps to create a new 32678 element list which is mapped to... You can probably get orders of magnitude of speed improvement by rewriting it to avoid all those lists.

Comment: I suppose I could give it a shot, it's a shame I have to use Shanon entropy. The above is the only one on CPAN. Thank you :)

Comment: (Er, 32678 * 1024 elements)

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean 32,768 (2**15)?

Comment: *"This yields an almost infinite wait time"* You would have to wait a very long time to test that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the entropy function re written to avoid all the map calls

```
sub entropy {
    my ($entropy, $len, $p, %t) = (0, length($_[0]));
    my @chars = split '', $_[0];
    $t{$_}++ foreach @chars;

    foreach (values %t) {
        $p = $_/$len;
        $entropy -= $p * log $p ;
    }       

    return $entropy / log 2;
}
```

It may work out faster for you

I've had second thoughts about this. You don't actually need to slurp the file into memory. `$len` is the length of the file which can be got from `-s $file_name` and `%t` is the frequency table which can be calculated by reading in a block at a time. So a version of the function to calculate the entropy of a file would be

```
sub file_entropy {
    my ($file_name) = @_;

    # Get number of bytes in file
    my $len = -s $file_name;
    my ($entropy, %t) = 0;

    open (my $file, '<:raw', $file_name) || die "Cant open $file_name\n";

    # Read in file 1024 bytes at a time to create frequancy table
    while( read( $file, my $buffer, 1024) ) {
        $t{$_}++ 
            foreach split '', $buffer;

        $buffer = '';
    }

    foreach (values %t) {
        my $p = $_/$len;
        $entropy -= $p * log $p ;
    }       

    return $entropy / log 2;
}
```

Comment: `open my $fh, '<:raw', $file_name or die qq{Cant open "$file_name" for input: $!}` is better. There is also no need for `binmode` afterwards.

Comment: What you first wrote is great, I am able to calculate a 32mb file in about 10-15 seconds, depending on the computer. Is there a quicker way? I would love to be able to calculate the entropy of multiple files in quick succession!

Comment: I sent the new code to the module maintainer (https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=127573)